# Error in Heroko but not in node./src/index.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I have this error in Heroku, but when I ran node./src/index.js , there's no error

```
2020-05-18T15:49:19.512214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-18T15:49:19.512651+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-18T15:49:19.514281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! litchbotv2@2.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2020-05-18T15:49:19.514520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-18T15:49:19.514835+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-05-18T15:49:19.515069+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the litchbotv2@2.0.0 start script.
2020-05-18T15:49:19.515341+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-18T15:49:19.533011+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-18T15:49:19.533013+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-18T15:49:19.533014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-18T15_49_19_516Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I found the solution, my bot had several commented codes, and this was overloading the bot, after deleting them, everything went back to working!

Comment: If someone can close the question, do it!